# Como assinar XML da NF-e no ASP.NET Core usando os padrões de assinatura da NF-e 4.00?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, assinatura-digital

Estou desenvolvendo uma API com o ASP.NET Core, fazendo a comunicação com a Sefaz para envio da NF-e, no entanto estou tendo um problema ao assinar o XML, abaixo está o código que faz a assinatura:

```c#
var listas = xmlAssinar.GetElementsByTagName(infosTipoOperacao.TagAssinatura);

foreach (XmlNode nodes in listas)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childNodes in nodes.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (!childNodes.Name.Equals(infosTipoOperacao.TagAtributoId))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Cria uma referência para ser assinado
        var reference = new Reference
        {
            DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1",
            Uri = string.Empty
        };

        // Pega o uri que deve ser assinada                                       
        var childElemen = (XmlElement)childNodes;

        if (childElemen.GetAttributeNode("Id") != null)
        {
            reference.Uri = string.Format("#{0}", childElemen.GetAttributeNode("Id").Value);
        }
        else if (childElemen.GetAttributeNode("id") != null)
        {
            reference.Uri = string.Format("#{0}", childElemen.GetAttributeNode("id").Value);
        }

        // Cria um objeto SignedXml
        var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlAssinar)
        {                            
            // Adicione a chave ao documento SignedXml
            SigningKey = certificadoDigital.PrivateKey
        };

        // Adiciona uma transformação envelopada à referência
        var env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        var c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(c14);

        // Adiciona a referência ao objeto SignedXml
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        // Cria um novo objeto KeyInfo
        var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

        // Carrega o certificado em um objeto KeyInfoX509Data e adicione-o ao objeto KeyInfo
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificadoDigital));

        // Adiciona o objeto KeyInfo ao objeto SignedXml
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Obtém a representação XML da assinatura e salve-a em um objeto XmlElement
        var xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Grava o elemento no documento XML
        nodes.AppendChild(xmlAssinar.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
    }
}

xmlAssinar.PreserveWhitespace = false;

return xmlAssinar;
```

Este código eu também utilizo no ASP.NET Framework e funciona normalmente, porém ao utilizar o Core, na validação da NFe me retorna o seguinte erro:

> The value of the 'Algorithm' attribute does not equal its fixed value

ou

> O valor do atributo 'Algoritmo' não é igual ao seu valor fixo

Foi então que percebi que dentro do objeto `PrivateKey` no Certificado Digital tem um retorno diferente do retorno do Framework e creio que isso está afetando o algoritmo que faz assinatura.

Comment: Qual o tipo do objeto que é retornado pela propriedade `certificadoDigital.PrivateKey`? Você já tentou usar o método de extensão `certificadoDigital.GetRSAPrivateKey()`?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que faltou informar o algoritmo (SHA1) que deve ser usado para a assinatura, com a seguinte linha:

```c#
signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha1";
```

Você indicou o SHA1 através da propriedade [`Reference.DigestMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.reference.digestmethod), mas é a propriedade [`SignedInfo.SignatureMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedinfo.signaturemethod) que define qual algoritmo será usado para a assinatura.

Aqui tem um exemplo com SHA256, mas dá para ter uma ideia:

> [EFD-Reinf: Erro Assinatura - Um Contexto XmlDocument é necessário para transformações envelopadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349264/86952)