# EFD-Reinf: Erro Assinatura - Um Contexto XmlDocument é necessário para transformações envelopadas

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# para o EFD-Reinf e na hora de enviar o meu evento R-1000 estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> "Um Contexto XmlDocument é necessário para transformações envelopadas."

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
public XmlDocument Assinar(string XMLString, X509Certificate2 X509Cert)
{
    //XmlDocument XMLDoc = null;

    string x = X509Cert.GetKeyAlgorithm().ToString();

    // Create a new XML document.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    // Format the document to ignore white spaces.
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

    // Load the passed XML file using it's name.
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

    byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLString.Trim());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);
    ms.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;

    doc.Load(ms);

    // Create a SignedXml object.
    SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

    // Add the key to the SignedXml document. 
    signedXml.SigningKey = X509Cert.PrivateKey;

    // Create a reference to be signed.
    Reference reference = new Reference();
    // pega o uri que deve ser assinada
    XmlAttributeCollection _Uri = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ReinfEvtInfoContriInfoContri").Item(0).Attributes;

    foreach (XmlAttribute _atributo in _Uri)
    {
        if (_atributo.Name == "id")
        {
            reference.Uri = "#" + _atributo.InnerText;
        }
    }

    // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
    XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    reference.AddTransform(env);

    // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);


    // Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(X509Cert));
    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

    // Compute the signature.
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
    // it to an XmlElement object.
    XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

    // Append the element to the XML document.
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

    if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
    {
        doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
    }

    XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XMLDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
    XMLDoc = doc;

    return XMLDoc;
}
```

Alguém sabe o motivo pelo qual estou recebendo esse erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você cometeu alguns erros nessa rotina:

- Você só está aplicando a transformação `EnvelopedSignature` mas não está aplicando a `C14N`;
- Você não está informando nas propriedades `SignatureMethod` e `DigestMethod` o algoritmo que deve ser usado, que é o SHA-256;
- E, não é um erro, mas, é desnecessário criar outro objeto `XmlDocument` no final da rotina, e também desnecessário informar a propriedade `PreserveWhitespace` 3 vezes durante a função.

Você pode fazer assim (copiei e modifiquei a função dessa minha [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/86952)):

```
public void Assinar(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate, string refUri)
{
   // Cria o objeto SignedXml baseado no XmlDocument passado.
   SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

   // Adiciona a chave privada do certificado ao documento SignedXml.
   signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
   // O método de extensão GetRSAPrivateKey() está disponível a partir
   // do .NET Framework 4.6, se for anterior a isso, use a linha abaixo:
   //signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;

   // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#Crypto462
   // The .NET Framework 4.6.2 adds support to the SignedXml class for RSA-SHA256,
   // RSA-SHA384, and RSA-SHA512 PKCS#1 signature methods, and SHA256, SHA384,
   // and SHA512 reference digest algorithms.
   signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url;        
   // O campo 'SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url' só está disponível a partir
   // do .NET Framework 4.6.2, se for anterior a isso, use a linha abaixo:
   //signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

   // Checa se foi informado um URI para a referência, se foi acrescenta o "#" no começo.
   refUri = String.IsNullOrEmpty(refUri) ? "" : $"#{refUri}";

   var reference = new Reference(refUri);
   reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
   reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
   reference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA256Url;
   // O campo 'SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA256Url' só está disponível a partir
   // do .NET Framework 4.6.2, se for anterior a isso, use a linha abaixo:
   //reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

   signedXml.AddReference(reference);

   // Carrega o certificado em um objeto KeyInfoX509Data e o adiciona ao objeto KeyInfo.
   signedXml.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
   signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

   // Calcula a assinatura.
   signedXml.ComputeSignature();

   // Obtém a representação XML da assinatura e a armazena em um objeto XmlElement.
   XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

   // Acrescenta o elemento ao documento XML.
   xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

   // Se o primeiro nó do documento for o nó de declaração XML
   // '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', remove ele.
   if (xmlDoc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
      xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
}
```

Eu optei por passar o ID do evento, que vai no atributo `Reference.URI`, como um parâmetro da função, o que facilita muito a vida.

A função recebe um objeto `XmlDocument` e acrescenta a assinatura nesse mesmo objeto, por isso ela não retorna nada. Se você estiver criando o `XmlDocument` a partir de um objeto `string`, você pode carrega-lo assim, antes de chamar essa função:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringXmlEvento);
```

Mas, pode ser também que esse erro esteja ocorrendo por você estar assinando o trecho errado do XML do evento. Veja essas duas outras respostas para ver exatamente o que precisa ser assinado:

- [Erro de assinatura do XML para o EFD-Reinf - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283284/86952)
- [EFD-Reinf - Versão do lote inválida. Deve ser utilizada a versão 1.04.00 - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344968/86952)

Aproveitando, veja também essas outras respostas, que talvez possam ajuda-lo:

- [Como consumir WebService do EFD-Reinf no C#? (Envio Eventos) - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343200/86952)
- [XSD.EXE Gerar classes no C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347864/86952)
- [C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Como instanciar e preencher todas propriedades dos Eventos? - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/348614/86952)

Comment: Pedro, obrigado pela colaboração. Após utilizar conforme voce orientou, agora recebo um erro de "Elemento Reference mal formado." na linha "signedXml.ComputeSignature()"
Sabe o que pode estar causando esse erro?

Comment: Você está usando a função de assinatura igual a que eu postei ou fez alguma alteração? O que está informando no parâmetro `refUri`? Ele deve ser exatamente igual ao atributo `id` do elemento `evtInfoContri` do seu XML do evento R-1000.